# Can I place two high charts side by side and keep the sizing dynamic?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Updated substantially to make my question more clear (I hope). I have data that I'm charting in columns to show change by year, and a sort of drill down that I'd like to put on a second X-axis to show the breakdown in the last year. If I do [this](http://jsfiddle.net/eFrD7/):

```
var yearbyyear = [
    [2002, 591856],
    [2003, 839446],
    [2004, 848463],
    [2005, 1034755],
    [2006, 1569442],
    [2007, 1484477],
    [2008, 2280282],
    [2009, 3261702],    
    [2010, 4132972],
    [2011, 5321516]
];

function createSeries(data, yAxisIndex) {
    var i;
    var series = [];
    for (i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) { // Node length-1
        var start = data[i];
        var end = data[i + 1];
        series.push({
            yAxis: yAxisIndex
        });
    }
    return series;
}


var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: [{
        min: 2002,
        tickInterval: 1
    }, {
        offset: 0,
        labels: false,
        left: 400,
        width: 100
    }],
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
        }
    },
    series: [{
        xAxis: 0,
        name: 'Year over Year',
        data: yearbyyear
    }, {
        xAxis: 1,
        name: 'Top Stack',
        data: [2011, 2770158]
    }, {
        xAxis: 1,
        name: 'Next Stack',
        data: [2011, 2551358]
    }]
};

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

The chart is fully fluid, but the series all overlap. I can keep them from overlapping, but only by giving the first chart an explicit width, and the second an x-offset to accommodate that width. Is there a way I can keep that fluidity but keep the second x-axis to the right of the first?

A commenter here pointed out that I can fudge the chart by putting the drilldown at 2012 on the same x-axis but I don't love the idea of introducing inaccuracy, even under the hood, by saying the data belongs to 2012 when it is definitely 2011 numbers.

Comment: So ... I made some progress: http://jsfiddle.net/amandabee/8D7J8/1/

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure where the problem is, you need to have separated series for different part as you have. So what is wrong with your chart?

Comment: 1) There's a weird y-axis line under the second chart that I can't get rid of; 2) It is always exactly X pixels wide. I can't expand /contract it to fit available space.

Comment: 1) Becasue you have two xAxis, remove it and use single xAxis with two series.

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd put the series on one xAxis -- right now I have two series stacked on the second xAxis.

Comment: See the example http://jsfiddle.net/8D7J8/7/